# Group Subject and teachers and improve code performance

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked about this question in an interview where I was given a string with teachers and the corresponding subjects they teach as input string. The task to to get subjects and the corresponding teachers as output. I have solved it but I have few questions:

- How to improve this to improve time and space complexity for this
  program.
- I said the time complexity is n square as I have used nested
  loops, is this correct?
- Can we solve this using Java 8 lambdas and
  streams in a better way?

Here is input for my program:

```
T1:S1,S3|T2:S1,S2,S4|T3:S1,S4,S5
```

Here T represents a teacher, S represents a Student. In above example Teacher T1 teaches subjects S1 & S3. Teacher T2 teaches subject S1, S2, S4 etc

Now the requirement is to get the Subject and the corresponding teachers.

```
["S1:T1,T2,T3", "S2:T2", "S3:T1", "S4:T2,T3", "S5:T3"]
```

It means Subject S1 is taught by teachers T1, T2, T3. Subject S2 is taught by T1 etc.

I have come up with below code that is working correctly:

```
    /**
     * input: "T1:S1,S3|T2:S1,S2,S4|T3:S1,S4,S5"
     * output : ["S1:T1,T2,T3", "S2:T2", "S3:T1", "S4:T2,T3", "S5:T3"]
     */
   static List<String> process(String input) {
     List<String> output = null;
      // Split by |
      String[] arr = input.split("\\|"); 

      Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

      // map with key as Teacher name and value as list of students
      for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
          String[] data = arr[i].split(":");
          map.put(data[0], Arrays.asList(data[1].split(",")));
      }

      Map<String, List<String>> res = new TreeMap<>();

      //Build map with key as student and value as list of teachers
      for(String key : map.keySet()) {
          List<String> list = map.get(key);
          for(String val : list) {
           List<String> temp = res.get(val);
           if(temp == null) {
               temp = new ArrayList<>();
               res.put(val, temp);
           }
           temp.add(key);
          }

      }


      output = new ArrayList<>();
      // Build the output as per requirement
      for(String key : res.keySet()) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          List<String> temp = res.get(key);
           for(String v : temp) 
           {
               sb.append(v).append(",");
           }
         output.add(key + ":" + sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1) );

      }

     return output;
   }
```

Can you please help me with these doubts.

Comment: Well, you are asking for improvement on your code but the site to ask it is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could skip the *"map with key as Teacher name"* and go directly to the *"map with key as student"*. In other words, while scanning the input, keep the name of the teacher, and then add the teacher to the list for each of the following students.

Comment: @user3386109, yes I can remove a for loop with that. What is the time complexity of the program after that, is it order of n square as I have nested for loops?

Comment: Assuming the `HashMap`, `String`, `List`, and `ArrayList` operations are all O(1), then the time complexity would be O(len(S)), where `len(S)` is the length of the input string. You can't do better than that, since you have to read the entire input string.

Answer (score 1):

Only answering the part where you want to convert it to Java 8 Stream API, so feel free not to accept this answer :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "T1:S1,S3|T2:S1,S2,S4|T3:S1,S4,S5";
    System.out.println(process(input));
}

private static List<String> process(String input) {
    return Arrays.stream(input.split("\\|"))
            .flatMap(s -> List.of(s.split(":")[1].split(","))
                    .stream()
                    .map(s1 -> s.split(":")[0] + ":" + s1))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.split(":")[1],
                    o -> o.split(":")[0],
                    (o1, o2) -> o1 + "," + o2))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Output**

```
[S3:T1, S4:T2,T3, S5:T3, S1:T1,T2,T3, S2:T2]
```